# Java mail read already read mails

Tags: email, spring-integration, jakarta-mail, imap

Is there an option to re-read mails from an Inbox (~1000s of emails per day) using Java mail API? We already have mail integration to read mails. Each time a mail is read by the application, mail gets marked as read and not eligible for second time (or subsequent) read.
However, is there an option to re-read already read mails using IMAP protocol in Java API?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Javamail and IMAP treat handle read and unread mail equally. Both do in fact offer options to toggle the seen flag.